# Tableadapter You must have Microsoft SQL 2005 or greater

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-2000

I just received a project that hasnt been touched in a while. It was written in VS2005 and SQl 2000. I upgraded the project to VS2010 with no problems. However; when I tried to modify the table adapters etc. I get the error "You must have Microsoft SQL 2005 or greater".

This project has 100's of datasets and table adapters all referencing SQL 2000.

I guess I have 2 questions:
Should I takeall these adapters out and make a data layer and connect to the DB that way?

Or can I upgrade the DB to SQL 2008 and it will all work the way it is? Not sure what is the best approach on this one.

And this is a desktop app if it matters.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect VS 2010 to a MSSQL 2000 db by selecting a SQL db and then the OLE option - then said remember password (yes, I know it's not encrypted).  That provided a connection string in the `projectname.exe.config` file that looks like:

```
<add name="projectname.My.MySettings.dbnameConnectionString"
     connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ip.ip.ip.ip; Persist Security Info=TRUE;Password=xxxxxxx;User ID=username; Inital Catalog=dbname"
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
<startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework, Version=4.0,Profile=Client" />
```

With this I get Messages on the last line here -

```
Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku' (and 'version' and element 'supportedRuntime')
```